# Custom button to create an opportunity

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to create a list button or button on task layout to create an opportunity since this task:
When I click on this button, I want to perform these operations:

```
Name of opportunity = Name of task,
Opportunity Account = Task Account, 
Contact of the opportunity = Contact of the task
Campaign of opportunity = campaign of the task,
Description of the opportunity = Description of the task.
```

How can i do that please ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Custom Button:

- Display Type: Detail Page Button
- Behaviour: Execute Javascrtipt
- Content Source: OnClick Javascrtipt

put a code that looks like this:

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js')}
    var opp = new sforce.SObject('Opportunity');

    opp.Account= '{!Task.What}';
    /// you can Map other fields here...   
    result = sforce.connection.create([opp ]); 
    var newurl = window.open.href;
    if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
       window.location = "/" + result[0].id + "/e";
    }else{
      alert('Could not create record '+result);
    }
```

Then add it in the Page Layout.

Comment: SObject Task does not have a field with API "Name". Also your code will blow up at runtime due to the fact you are attempting to reference Contact column on entity Opportunity.

Comment: You are right, I have posted the How to use a Javascipt Button.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i must to do like that ? :opp.Account= '{!Task.What}'                          opp.Contact= '{!Task.Contact}'                                                               opp.Campaaigne= '{!Task.Campaigne}'                                                                   opp.Description= '{!Task.Description}'